# Localization of strings which is inside a plugin dll C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, culture

I am creating a wpf application which contains several self contained plugin dlls which are accessed by my main application. Is there any way to provide localization support such that all the localized strings comes from inside the dll?

Example: 
Main app accesses Plugin1 or Plugin2 using predefined interface according to the scenario.
Plugin1 and Plugin2 performs entirely different functions depending on the case and displays corresponding strings from inside the plugin dll. (These strings has to be localized to current culture)

Note: 
1. Once setup, main app should not have any changes for a plugin change (obviously)
2. Plugins should not have resources outside

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, so correct me.

In my shop we simply include resource files in the referenced DLLs. We take those resource files and send them to a translation service. I think as long as you're storing all of your localizable strings in resource files, as opposed to hard coding them, you should be ok in terms of localization.

Another thing to consider, however, is screen real estate. Some character sets take up more space than others. This is usually a problem for us when we make the translation from U.S. English to Chinese.